# Cannot make CRON work for user on CentOS 7

Tags: cron, centos, centos7

This is file `/var/spool/cron/[USER]`:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root

0 */2 * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - http://[WEBSITE]/[STUFF] >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I made this CRON to visit website every second hour. But it is not working, because when I type command about CRON status, then it says this:

```
$ systemctl status crond
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded ...
   Active: active (running) ...

...
crond[6967]: (CRON) bad minute (/var/spool/cron/[USER])
...
```

It is weird, because when I move it to the `/var/spool/cron/root`, then it works. This "bad minute" shows only for other users. But why?

CHMOD is 600 and owner is the user I talk about.

Comment: Use the `crontab` command to maintain crontabs. Don't manipulate files under `/var/spool/cron` directly.

Comment: I will try. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't edit the cron file directly, have you tried editing it when logged in to the correct user with this command:

```
crontab -e
```

Also check that your /etc/crontab file is correct

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# run-parts
01 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
02 4 * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.daily
22 4 * * 0 root run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
42 4 1 * * root run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Comment: Yay! It's working, didn't know I can't edit that file directly, but with crontab.